# transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult does not throw if transaction failed

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-data

I am using spring-tx with a PostgreSQL database. In the below test snippet, an SQL exception happens within a transaction ("TX: Second Insert") and is swallowed within the code.

If the exception was caught within the Java code, can the caller of `transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult` get some feedback indicating when the transaction had failed and rolled back?

```
void testSwallowingNonSerializationException() {
  TransactionTemplate transactionTemplate = new TransactionTemplate(manager);

  transactionTemplate.executeWithoutResult(
      (t) -> {
        log.info("TX: First Insert");
        dslContext.insertInto(Author.AUTHOR).values(100, "lucky", "you").execute();
        log.info("TX: First Insert done");
        try {
          log.info("TX: Second Insert");
          dslContext.insertInto(Author.AUTHOR).values(100, "lucky", "you").execute();
          log.info("TX: Second insert done");
        } catch (Exception e) {
          log.error("TX: Second insert failed", e);
          log.info("TX: Swallow exception {}", e.getMessage());
        }
      });

  // Note: no exception thrown from transaction() method..

  Assertions.assertThrows(
      java.util.NoSuchElementException.class,
      () -> {
        val author =
            dslContext
                .selectFrom(Author.AUTHOR)
                .where(Author.AUTHOR.ID.eq(100))
                .fetchOptional()
                .orElseThrow()
                .into(Author.class);
        System.out.println(author);
      });
}
```

Comment: Can you just re-throw an exception inside the catch block?

Comment: I think the idea here is second insert can be any code which catches any exception and the `testSwallowingNonSerializationException()` code may not have access to modify that code.